# how to unwrap a mesh made in front of the texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I used an image texture as a background image and created a mesh in front of it. Now I want to use the background image as a texture with the same size as the background image.
The unwrapping does not work the way I want it to. I only unwrapped the front of my mesh which is based on the background image, but the mesh and the image apparently do not have the same scale and so it does not fit the texture.
Moving the unwrapped vertices around distorts the texture.
So how can I make the UV map perfectly fit and have the same proportions as the front of the mesh?

Answer (score 1):

Try unwrapping with <kbd>U</kbd>*>Project from view* while in the view with the background image.

Then use <kbd>S</kbd> (scale), <kbd>R</kbd> (rotate), and <kbd>G</kbd> (grab/translate) to manipulate the entire UV layout (you can toggle selecting it with <kbd>A</kbd>).

If you want to unwrap it *exactly* how it appears in the viewport:

1. Set the render resolution to the resolution of the image/texture
2. Wit the camera selected, set it to be *Orthographic* in *Properties > Object data > Lens* (you can add another camera with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and make it active with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> if you don't want to disturb the existing one)
3. Position the camera and tweak the *Orthographic scale*, again in *Properties > Object Data > Lens*. With the background image allowed to display in camera view, you can line it up based on how you want the image to project on your mesh.
4. Select your object and enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), then press <kbd>U</kbd>*>Project from view* (still in camera view).

[image]